# multidimensional array value insert into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

```
array (size=11)
  'reward_title' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'kishan' (length=6)
      1 => string 'asd' (length=3)
  'amount' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '100' (length=3)
      1 => string '200' (length=3)
  'description' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'k' (length=1)
      1 => string 'kk' (length=2)
  'estimated_delivery' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '02/02/2017' (length=10)
      1 => string '02/03/2017' (length=10)
  'shipping_details' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
  'ship_amount_country' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
  'ship_anywhere_world' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
  'limit_avail' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'on' (length=2)
      1 => string 'on' (length=2)
  'backer_limit' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '2' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
  'avail_from' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
  'avail_until' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '8' (length=1)
```

**database table**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ8mJ.jpg)

multidimensional array value insert into database using codeigniter
help me.

Comment: RTFM https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data See `$this->db->insert_batch()`

Comment: Seriously, explain what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: OP need his given array conversion to codeigniter multi insert array. I hope I am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,

This will be your own function code,

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
        $data[$k1][] = [$k => $v1];
    }
}
foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
    $a        = $this->array_2d_to_1d($v);
    $result[] = $a;
}
$this->db->set($result);

$this->db->insert_batch('table', $result);
```

And make another function in that controller as

```
function array_2d_to_1d($input_array)
{
    $output_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input_array); $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($input_array[$i]); $j++) {
            $output_array[key($input_array[$i])] = $input_array[$i][key($input_array[$i])];
        }
    }
    return $output_array;
}
```

I am sure this will work.

Comment: ok i am trying..............

Comment: i don't unsderstand your code

Comment: $array variable will be your array

Comment: I will make you understand, first try it.

Comment: please write code in above array

Comment: ok.............

Comment: tell me function array_2d_to_1d ($input_array) which work and which call?

Comment: You see this line, $a = array_2d_to_1d($v); so make array_2d_to_1d function somewhere in your controller and call it by $this->array_2d_to_1d($v) like this. I have made changes in code once check that line

Comment: I made more clear changes check now

Comment: which place to put function array_2d_to_1d($input_array) {}functio controller or model?

Comment: In controller, I mentioned everything in answer itself, once refresh the page and check

Comment: please check below my controller code:

Comment: class Rewards extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('rewards_model');
       
    }
    
    public function add(){
   
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            var_dump($_POST);
            $this->rewards_model->insert($_POST);
        }

        $data = array(
            'page_title'=>'Rewards',
            'page_name'=>'rewards/add'
        );
        $this->load->view('site/template',$data);
    
  }
}

Comment: below model:   class Rewards_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function insert($rew){

    
 }
        
           
}

Comment: i send controller and model code and please write your code in mycode

Comment: I am sure you know how to add new function inside controller, right ?

Comment: mate, you seriously don't know how to write new function inside controller ? Just copy and paste. Thats I am not gonna guide anyway

Comment: i can create function array_2d_to_1d($input_array) in controller and perform code but some error on your code

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Comment: You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: C:/Apache24/htdocs/kickstarter/system/database/DB_query_builder.php

Comment: Have you changed, table name ? And yes, initialize result like $result = []; and once print_r($result) and check if you are getting data.

Comment: Check answer I have added $this->db->set($result);

Comment: @ rahul_m your answer very grateful , thanks for my help